# Что делать, если получаешь сообщение «Сообщение не отвечает стандартам качества сообщества»?

Tags: поддержка, faq, вопросы

При попытке задать вопрос я получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

> Ой! Ваш вопрос не может быть отправлен по следующей причине:
>
> - Сообщение не отвечает стандартам качества сообщества

- Почему я получаю эту ошибку?
- Что мне сделать, чтобы система приняла мой вопрос?
- Можете ли вы объяснить подробнее суть ошибки?

> Более подробно см. [«Почему я вижу сообщение, что мой вопрос не отвечает стандартам качества?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) в [справочном центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

---

<sub>Перевод «[What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/)»</sub>.

Comment: Это к вопросам на мете тоже применяется?

Comment: @Grundy На Мете фильтры качества так же активированы, но, возможно, учитывая специфику Меты, список рекомендаций будет выглядеть иначе.

Comment: просто при дефектах типа локализации - когда просто описание места и картинка - не хватает чтобы пройти :-)

Comment: Предлагаю из вышеуказанного раздела справки сделать ссылку сюда.

Answer (score 6):

## Для основного сайта Stack Overflow на русском

#### Почему я получаю эту ошибку?

Все новые вопросы проходят через фильтр «качества», который проверяет вопрос на наличие типичных характеристик откровенно плохого вопроса. Ваш вопрос не прошел этот фильтр.

#### Что мне сделать, чтобы система приняла мой вопрос?

> Убедитесь, что вы:
>
> - ясно и однозначно сформулировали заголовок;
> - понятно *сформулировали* вопрос, приведя **ваше собственное предварительное исследование вопроса**;
> - используете грамматически верные конструкции;
> - при написании заголовка и объяснения соблюдаете правила орфографии и пунктуации.
>
> Если ваш вопрос так банален, что его можно решить, просто заглянув в словарь или справочник, для нашей сети сайтов он, скорее всего, не подходит.

#### Можете ли вы объяснить подробнее суть ошибки?

Подробности алгоритма командой не разглашаются.

> Я против излишних подробностей в этом вопросе… Наша проверка учитывает содержание меток, заголовка и тела вопроса. Но мы не планируем предоставлять подробные объяснения в каждом конкретном случае.
>   Кроме того, если мы раскроем нашу «формулу», у пользователей появится еще один способ обойти фильтры.

Comment: Предположим, что я убедился. Мой вопрос сформулирован точно и лаконично, лишён всяких "здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане", понятен и однозначен. Но система всё равно требует добавить в него какого-то шлака. А на Мете пишут, что мой вопрос банален. Ну и ладно, пойду-ка я на другой сайт.

Comment: @NickVolynkin На моей практике такое случается крайне редко. Качество ответов от знатоков на Stack Overflow стоит того, чтобы потратить дополнительные три минуты на переформулирование вопроса. Если же вовсе отключить фильтры, то уровень вопросов может сильно упасть, а как результат, и эффективность время/ответ, так как участникам потребуется дополнительное время на уточняющие комментарии (и ожидание улучшающих правок).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Более того, фильтры можно настраивать. Сейчас на Stack Overflow на русском крайне низкий порог (например, «[Java Spring MVC](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543620/6)»).

Comment: странно, что на основном сайте такой вопрос можно опубликовать, а на Мете - нет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, потому что мета - чтобы поговорить :-D

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky моё первое предложение - скорее про Мету. Я считаю некорректным называть краткие вопросы на Мете банальными. Тем более, что чаще всего фильтр срабатывает на багрепортах.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, надо что–то с этим делать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хватит это терпеть! =)

Answer (score 6):

## Для Меты Stack Overflow на русском

Убедитесь, что ваш вопрос сформулирован точно, полно и понятно. Вот идеи того, чем можно дополнить ваш вопрос:

- Если вопрос описывает [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82): сделайте скриншот и/или добавьте пошаговую инструкцию для воспроизведения. Расскажите, как функционал сайта должен работать.
- Если это [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) локализации и у вас есть доступ в Transifex - пожалуйста, найдите нужную строку и опубликуйте ссылку.
- Если это [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), можно подробнее описать смысл, целесообразность и подробности реализации.
- Если вам требуется [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0) по вопросам использования сайта, расскажите немного подробнее, с какими затруднениями вы столкнулись.  Кстати, лишний раз поищите на Мете и в [Справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). Вполне возможно, что ответ уже есть.
- Если вы инициируете [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), напишите несколько предложений о своей точке зрения.

Алгоритм фильтрации бывает слишком строгим для вопросов на Мете. Если ваш вопрос уже содержит всё, что нужно, но система всё ещё считает его слишком коротким - не нужно добавлять в вопрос лишнего.

Вы можете, например, дублировать текущий текст вопроса, опубликовать, а сразу после публикации удалить лишний текст.

Comment: _делайте скриншот и/или добавьте пошаговую инструкцию для воспроизведения._ - скриншот и строка - откройте сниппет - не помогает :-)

Comment: @Grundy тогда последние два абзаца. )

Comment: да вот так и получается :-) хотя странно, что после редактирования он позволяет сохранить короткий текст

Answer (score -2):

## Для всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange

1. Добавить в заголовок вопроса:

   > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
2. Добавить в текст вопроса:

   > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   >
   > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
3. Опубликовать вопрос.
4. Удалить Lorem Ipsum.

Последний шаг важно сделать быстро: в течение пяти минут и до первого комментария, тогда Lorem Ipsum не сохранится в истории правок вопроса.

Comment: а в заголовок то зачем?

Comment: @Grundy К заголовкам у движка тоже бывают претензии.

Comment: Да? ни разу на такое не попадал, еще страньше :)

Comment: Лучше уж спросить на английской Мете: "Хочу задать вот такой вопрос, но система отфутболивает за плохое качество. Научите, что поправить." Уверен, что будет толковый совет.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Какой может быть толковый ответ? "Выразите мысль с помощью более длинных слов"? У нас эта проблема возникает в основном на Мете, когда обсуждаются баги локализации. По-хорошему надо бы при наличии меток "локализация" и "дефект" делать условия мягче, но это специфика одной Меты одного сайта, поэтому вряд ли кому-то будет до этого дело.

Comment: 1. Обращаю внимание, что мы комментируем ответ "Для всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange". 2. Не попробуешь - не узнаешь. Зачем за других решать, что они ответят?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Ну попробуйте, напишите, я вас не держу. :)

Comment: Уже пробовал. Ненужное заминусовали, интересное поддержали, над забавным похохмили. И всё растолковали, о чём спросил.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Аккаунт на МСЕ не заметил. На МСО один вопрос закрыли, другой заминусовали, третий проигнорировали (нет, два плюсика — это не поддержка). Для статистики: на два ваших отвеченных вопроса я бы ответил примерно так же. Ну знаю я, как тут всё работает.

Comment: Я говорю про то, что "спросить на английской Мете"  продуктивней подставного "Lorem ipsum". И, похоже, что сказал это уже четвёртый раз. Ваше мнение я услышал.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Зачем спрашивать? Конструктивные ответы сверху, заплюсованные. А у меня деструктивный, заминусованный. Всё правильно.