# Улучшение страницы справки «Почему я вижу сообщение, что мой вопрос не отвечает стандартам качества?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Улучшение страницы справки «[Почему я вижу сообщение, что мой вопрос не отвечает стандартам качества?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error)».

---

Иногда, при публикации вопроса, участники видят предупреждение:

> «Это сообщение не отвечает нашим стандартам качества»

Если вы видите это предупреждение, ваш вопрос был автоматически заблокирован сервером.

Все публикуемые на сайте вопросы проходят через фильтр «минимально необходимого качества», который проверяет сообщение на основные показатели хорошего и полного вопроса. Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что ваш вопрос соответствует следующим критериям:

- Заголовок вопроса [понятен](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3342/).
- Тело вопроса содержит осмысленное объяснение сути вопроса в деталях.
- Приведена информация всех предварительно проведенных исследований проблемы.
- Содержимое вопроса не содержит грамматических и пунктуационных ошибок.

Дополнительную информацию о предупреждении и способах улучшения вопроса вы можете найти на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3369/6)

Если ваш вопрос соответствует всем приведенным выше пунктам, но вы всё ещё получаете предупреждение о блокировке отправки на сервер, и полагаете, что это ошибка, пожалуйста, свяжитесь с нами через [форму обратной связи](/contact).

На странице справочного центра «[Как задавать вопросы](/help/how-to-ask)» вы можете найти подробное руководство, как правильно описывать проблему в вопросе.

Comment: Пора уже такую метаметку создавать... Постоянно такие вопросы появляются...